# I make an attempt in writing 2 [2x2] matrices side by side in matlab and then send it in an excel sheet, How I will succeed that?

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

The following matlab code writes 4 columns [2x1] in an excel sheet side by side, making a [4x4] matrix.
`y = zeros(2,4); % I must make a zero matrix before I fill it`
`for i = 1:4 % 4 iterations for 4 columns`
`y(:,i) = rand(2,1); % saving the columns in the 'y' matrix`
`xlswrite('Book2.xlsx',y,'A1') % writing the columns one by one in the excel sheet`
`end`   Its ok over here. But I would like to write 2 [2x2] matrices side by side. Then I change the code,
`y = zeros(2,4);`
`for i = 1:2 % two iterations instead of 4`
`y(:,i) = rand(2,2); % now I have 2 [4x4] matrices instead of 4 [2x1] columns`
`xlswrite('Book2.xlsx',y,'A1')`
`end`
Unfortunately I get the following error: 
*Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts*
How can I succeed to my target by overcoming the error?
Is there any idea?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to do now? 2 [4x4] or 2 [2x2] matrices? If the first is the case, then `y = zeros(2,4);` is wrong, because 2 matrices of size [4x4] would give either a final size of 2x8 or 8x2 not 2x4 (as specified as parameters to `zeros`). Furthermore, the error comes from this line: `y(:,i) = rand(2,2);`. In this case `y(:,i)` is [2x1] because you defined it like `y = zeros(2,4);`, but `rand(2,2);` is [2x2], that means you cant assign it. So I guess you want it like this: `y(:,2*(i-1):2*i-1) = rand(2,2);`

Comment: Why is `xlswrite` inside your loop? Wouldn't it make more sense to calculate all your data in MATLAB and only once you have it all make one single call to `xlswrite`? If that is the case then consider changing your erroring line to `y{i} = rand(2,2)` and move your call to `xlswrite` outside your loop and change it to be `xlswrite('Book2.xlsx', [y{:}], 'A1')`. In this case you would also drop the `y = zeros(2,4)`. Another option is to use a 3D matrix instead of a cell array i.e. to make `y = zeros(2,2,2)` and then `reshape` before you `xlswrite`